# php safe output

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a "remember fields" thingy, so if there is one error you won't have to fill in the whole form again. But how can I make the output safe?

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['email'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) : ''; ?>" />
```

If someone types in " ' " (without the quotes) for example you get:

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\pages\register.php on line 55
```

So then I tried:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['email'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : ''; ?>" />
```

Then it just adds a lot of //////.

What should I do?

I'm a noob yes. But I thought htmlspecialchars made user input safe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix this error "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571907/how-to-fix-this-error-mysql-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-b)

Answer (score 8):

It depends on context.

`htmlspecialchars()` is your friend in HTML.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is your friend in MySQL.

#### Update

You could run all your `$_POST` through `htmlspecialchars()` first with this...

```
$encodedHtmlPost = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $_POST);
```

Comment: or, Output = `htmlspecialchars`, DB Input = `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use mysql_real_escape_string() before you put data in database, not for the output! It will prevent SQL injections. Use htmlspecialchars when outputting data to user, it prevents XSS attacks.

When inserting in database:

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1(data) VALUES('$data')"); //Safe insertion
```

When outputting to user:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($data);
```

Comment: There is no such thing like injection but improperly formatted query only. Prepared statements are the proper way to be 100% safe, read more at https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection Data should be stored unmodified! htmlspecialchars() seems a good way to go for the html-output, see answer of mario.

Answer (score 2):

As for html escaping, you should use a wrapper function because `htmlspecialchars` needs some parameters to produce reliably safe output:

```
 htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```